# contiki/examples/ipv6/rpl-collect/udp-sink.c file function "tcpiphandler" is not being called for z1 motes in Cooja Simulator

Tags: iot, contiki, cooja

I am trying to extract the sequence number for each packet of all the Z1 motes in my simulation. The problem is that, the function (tcpiphaandler in udp-sink.c) does not get called but the nodes are sending packets to each other in the simulation.

I have tried to print my name (using printf command) under the "tcpiphandler" function to check if it works or not and unfortunately it does nothing.

Comment: So what is your question sir ?

Comment: Hi, if you want help with your code, please provide a [mcve].